# how to upload a video while recording in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, video, rtmp, live-streaming

Hi I am developing app based on broadcast i am able to capture the video using videocore annd vcsimplesession using below code

```
 _session = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(320, 258) frameRate:30 bitrate:200000 useInterfaceOrientation:NO cameraState:_session.cameraState];
[self.previewView addSubview:_session.previewView];
_session.previewView.frame = self.previewView.bounds;
_session.delegate = self;

switch(_session.rtmpSessionState)
{
    case VCSessionStateNone:[_session continuousAutofocus];
    case VCSessionStatePreviewStarted:
    case VCSessionStateEnded:
    case VCSessionStateError:
        NSLog(@"///////////////////////////////////////////////vcsession error%ld",(long)VCSessionStateError);
        [_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"rtmp://zzz.tv"
                             andStreamKey:@"sA"];
        //[self bitrate];
        break;
    default:
        [_session endRtmpSession];
        break;

}
```

I am usig RTMP for broadcastig via wowza server 
but i want upload that video while recording to php server fro there i will get the url for broadcast I reffered some links like cmsamplerbuffer but i don't know how to upload video frame by frame while recording so can any body please tell me

Comment: hello i have the same problem, did you find the solution??